# Is there an replacement for AppFabric on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, appfabric

AppFabric is only available on Windows 2008 (and higher). Are there any similar packages that provide similar functionality on Windows 2003?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you need.
For the Distributed cache, I would take a look at [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).

For the WCF services hosting and management I Don't think you can find a replacement that does not involve changing your entire platform/architecture.